# Magento: product HTML generated by list.phtml, but Debugger won't stop?

Tags: magento

I modified `app\design\frontend\default\mytheme\template\catalog\product\list.phtml` and my mods are working fine, except for 2 products.

So I decided to debug a bit. I added this line:

```
if($_product->getId() == 12345) {
   echo 'something';
}
```

It just wont show *something*, I am sure it is the right product id, because I am outputting the product id on the `list.phtml` page below every product. It even wont stop if I place a breakpoint inside the if.

If I change the product id in the `if` to some other number, it displays *something*.

I just dont know why this is not working. Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Solved:** I solved this by moving some of my code a bit durther down in the script. No idea why this makes a difference for only those 2 products. But anyway, you put me on the right track, thanks!

Comment: _curious ...._ Place a `else` after the `if` conditions and check if `product id` is ok. Like this : `echo ($_product->getId == 12345) ? $_product->getId.' !=12345'  : $_product->getId.'==12345' ;` Your `product id` show up in `if` condition or in `else` condition ?

Comment: It says !=, but when I just display the id, it is 12345. You forgot the () for getId by the way. I added them.

Comment: In your script it's `$_product->getId()` or `$_product->getId` _without `()`_ ?

Comment: so .. when your product id is 12345, php consider product id not equal to 12345. Can you test this : `echo ($_product->getId() == 12345) ? $_product->getId().':'.gettype($_product->getId()).' != 12345' : $_product->getId().':'.gettype($_product->getId())' == 12345' `

Comment: I am using getId(), so with brackets.

Comment: I solved it, see updated post, thanks!

Comment: Nice ! Have a good day ; )